# Why was 1 << 31 changed to be implementation-defined in C++14?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, c++14

In all versions of C and C++ prior to 2014, writing

```
1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1)
```

caused undefined behaviour, because left-shifting is defined as being equivalent to successive multiplication by `2`, and this shift causes signed integer overflow:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

However in C++14 the text has changed for `<<` but not for multiplication:

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. [...] Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the **corresponding unsigned type** of the result type, then that value, **converted to the result type**, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The behaviour is now the same as for out-of-range assignment to signed type, i.e. as covered by [conv.integral]/3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, **the value is implementation-defined**.

This means it's still non-portable to write `1 << 31` (on a system with 32-bit int). So why was this change made in C++14?

Comment: +1 Howard Hinnant [comments on this topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593938/is-left-shifting-a-negative-integer-undefined-behavior-in-c11#comment29091986_19593938), the only reason I remember that comment is that comment was part of my inspiration for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413/1708801).

Comment: Imagine if they had instead simply stated something like: "Constraints: After promotion, the  left operand E1 shall be an unsigned integer type". It would have saved mankind from astronomic amounts of subtle, shift-related bugs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The relevant issue is [CWG 1457](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1457), where the justification is that the change allows `1 << 31` to be used in constant expressions:

> The current wording of 5.8 [expr.shift] paragraph 2 makes it undefined
>   behavior to create the most-negative integer of a given type by
>   left-shifting a (signed) 1 into the sign bit, even though this is not
>   uncommonly done and works correctly on the majority of
>   (twos-complement) architectures:
>
> > ...if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 * 2<sup>E2</sup> is
> >     representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value;
> >     otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> As a result, this technique
>   cannot be used in a constant expression, which will break a
>   significant amount of code.

Constant expressions can't contain undefined behavior, which means that using an expression containing UB in a context requiring a constant expression makes the program ill-formed. libstdc++'s `numeric_limits::min`, for example, [once failed to compile in clang](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52119) due to this.

Comment: Writer of that wording seems confused... the new rule doesn't allow one to "create the most-negative integer of a given type by left-shifting a (signed) 1 into the sign bit" either.  The result is implementation-defined, which is a far cry from being guaranteed to give the most-negative value.

Comment: @BenVoigt For two's complement there is only one sane result. And that is consistently implemented in all relevant and common compilers.

Comment: @Loopunroller: The last Standard quote in the question is worded that way to avoid requiring that conversion of an unsigned value to signed follow two's-complement rules.  Also, it's not true that for two's complement there is only one sane result.  Saturating arithmetic is also a useful, sane choice.  One could even say that's more sane than doubling a positive value creating a negative.

Comment: Was it actually so painful to have to write `- max() - 1` that they decided to change the standard instead?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Perhaps Howard Hinnant will see this and comment on whether he has other cases of code breakages in mind.

Comment: +1 Fwiw, libc++ computes `max()` in terms of `min()`, and so writing `min()` in terms of `max()` would have been excessively entertaining. :-)  Bottom-line as far as I'm concerned: I'm tired of standing on my head to support architectures which are not targeted by **any** modern C++ compiler. Two's complement signed integers are our reality, now, and in the future.

Comment: @Columbo: That there may only be one sane behavior for something does not prevent compilers from implementing crazy behaviors.