# Why is 0x7FFFFFFFull | (1 << 31) returning 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

When I do (0x7fffffff | 0x8000000) I am getting 0xffffffffffffffff instead of the expected 0xffffffff. What am I missing?

Some sample code and output to illustrate my question.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        unsigned long long val = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                val |= 0x1 << i;
                cout << i << ": " << std::hex << val << std::dec << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 1
1: 3
2: 7
3: f
4: 1f
5: 3f
6: 7f
7: ff
8: 1ff
9: 3ff
10: 7ff
11: fff
12: 1fff
13: 3fff
14: 7fff
15: ffff
16: 1ffff
17: 3ffff
18: 7ffff
19: fffff
20: 1fffff
21: 3fffff
22: 7fffff
23: ffffff
24: 1ffffff
25: 3ffffff
26: 7ffffff
27: fffffff
28: 1fffffff
29: 3fffffff
30: 7fffffff
31: ffffffffffffffff
32: ffffffffffffffff
33: ffffffffffffffff
34: ffffffffffffffff
35: ffffffffffffffff
36: ffffffffffffffff
37: ffffffffffffffff
38: ffffffffffffffff
39: ffffffffffffffff
40: ffffffffffffffff
41: ffffffffffffffff
42: ffffffffffffffff
43: ffffffffffffffff
44: ffffffffffffffff
45: ffffffffffffffff
46: ffffffffffffffff
47: ffffffffffffffff
48: ffffffffffffffff
49: ffffffffffffffff
50: ffffffffffffffff
51: ffffffffffffffff
52: ffffffffffffffff
53: ffffffffffffffff
54: ffffffffffffffff
55: ffffffffffffffff
56: ffffffffffffffff
57: ffffffffffffffff
58: ffffffffffffffff
59: ffffffffffffffff
60: ffffffffffffffff
61: ffffffffffffffff
62: ffffffffffffffff
63: ffffffffffffffff
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly your code does not do what you say in your title/question; I have edited the title.

The problem is `1 << 31`. If you have 32-bit `int` (which apparently you do, judging by the results), this cause arithmetic overflow.  In C++14 this is implementation-defined behaviour; prior to C++14 it causes undefined behaviour. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331035/why-was-1-31-changed-to-be-implementation-defined-in-c14).

Usually the implementation-defined behaviour will be to generate the int with the sign bit set and the other bits unset. In 2's complement this value is `INT_MIN`.  You then perform arithmetic between an `unsigned long long` and an `int`. This is defined as: the `int` is converted to `unsigned long long`.

Converting signed integers to unsigned is done by wrapping it around (modular arithmetic) modulo `ULLONG_MAX+1`.  So the result of `(unsigned long long)INT_MIN` is a very large positive number, in fact `0xFFFFFFFF80000000`.  (To check this, add `0x80000000` to it to get `0`).

So you are actually doing `0x7FFFFFFF | 0xFFFFFFFF80000000` which gives the observed result.

---

Later on it gets worse: `1 << 32` and larger causes undefined behaviour due to shifting by the whole width of the type.

To fix this, change `0x1` in your code to `1ull`.  The you will be shifting an `unsigned long long`, instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

because of sign extension `val` is an unsigned long long. But val is not what you are shifting. You are shifting 0x1, an int, then extending it to long long for the '|='