# Why is the binary equivalent calculation getting incorrect?

Tags: c++, binary

I wrote the following program to output the binary equivalent of a integer taking(I checked that int on my system is of 4 bytes) it is of 4 bytes. But the output doesn't come the right. The code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

void printBinary(int k){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 31; i++){
        if(k & ((1 << 31) >> i))
            cout << "1";
        else 
            cout << "0";
    }
}

int main(){
    printBinary(12);
}
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You didn't provide what actually happens and what you were expecting isntead.

Comment: + Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: + Maybe let us know what do you think you are getting wrong? Hard to tell you where you get something wrong if you don't tell us what confuses you...

Comment: @Zaibis, It's 2015. C++ is C++14 unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @DonReba Pray tell, how many (popular) compilers use something other than C++03 as the default?

Comment: @SchighSchagh, Visual C++. gcc can't do it for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @DonReba: How you dare to now even throw in words about Visual C++? Visual C++ isn't even C++ it isn't respecting the iso documents...

Answer (score 29):

The problem is in `1<<31`. Because 2<sup>31</sup> cannot be represented with a 32-bit signed integer (range −2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1), the result is undefined <sup>[1]</sup>.

The fix is easy: `1U<<31`.

---

<sub>[1]: The behavior is implementation-defined since C++14.</sub>

Comment: [Since C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331035/why-was-1-31-changed-to-be-implementation-defined-in-c14) there is no UB

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I don't see the OP tagged as C++14

Comment: @MattMcNabb: your phrasing sounds like you want to show that Yu Hao is incorrect. My point is, he isn't since the OP wasn't stating a specific version.

Comment: @Zaibis He is incorrect regarding the current version of C++. I am trying to give additional information .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: And I tryed to prevent confusion for future readers. So I'd say we did well my friend ;)

Answer (score 8):

This expression is incorrect:

```
if(k & ((1<<31)>>i))
```

`int` is a *signed* type, so when you shift `1` 31 times, it becomes the sign bit on your system. After that, shifting the result right `i` times *sign-extends* the number, meaning that the top bits remain `1`s. You end up with a sequence that looks like this:

```
80000000 // 10000...00
C0000000 // 11000...00
E0000000 // 11100...00
F0000000 // 11110...00
F8000000
FC000000
...
FFFFFFF8
FFFFFFFC
FFFFFFFE // 11111..10
FFFFFFFF // 11111..11
```

To fix this, replace the expression with `1 & (k>>(31-i))`. This way you would avoid undefined behavior<sup>*</sup> resulting from shifting `1` to the sign bit position.

<sup>*</sup> [C++14 changed the definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331170/335858) so that shifting `1` 31 times to the left in a 32-bit `int` is no longer undefined (Thanks, Matt McNabb, for pointing this out).

Comment: While it's technically correct explanation looking at how the instructions are executed on the machine, the language standard leaves the behavior undefined for `1 << 31`. From the specs: `The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. [...] Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @nhahtdh That's why I wrote that this is the behavior on OP's system.

Comment: I think you should make it more prominent, and also clarify the fact that while your fix may be correct on the OP's system, it is undefined behavior according to the specs.

Answer (score 4):

A typical internal memory representation of a signed integer value looks like:

[image]

> The **m**ost **s**ignificant **b**it (first from the right) is the sign bit and in `signed numbers`(like `int`) it represents whether the number is negative or not. 
>   When you shift additional bits **sign extension** is performed to preserve the number's sign. This is done by **appending digits to the most significant side of the number**.(following a procedure dependent on the particular signed number representation used). 
>  
>   In unsigned numbers the first bit from the right **is just the MSB** of the represented number, thus when you shift additional bits no sign extension is performed.

Note: the enumeration of the bits starts from *0*, so `1 << 31` replaces your sign bit and after that every bit shift operation to the left `>>` results in sign extension. (as pointed out by @dasblinkenlight)

So, the simple solution to your problem is to make the number unsigned (this is what `U` does in `1U << 31`) before you start the bit manipulation. (as pointed out by @Yu Hao)

For further reading see [signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) and [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).(as it's the most common)